# Move just one match

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking, matches

Make a correct equation by just moving one matchstick!

[image]

[This is the source.  Spoiler--source reveals answer.](https://www.funwithpuzzles.com/2018/12/simple-matchstick-math-riddle-and-answer.html)

Comment: You know the source reveal the answer, right?

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath I didn't pay attention to it. I mean I didn't know. But I think that's the cheater's problem to look at it; not mine or non-cheaters.

Comment: @aminabuzz -- I mean, if you're revealing the answer in the question, it's not a great question, is it?

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath It's better to provide a link if the question isn't your own creation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Moving one:

> [image]
>
> From the '+' to make a '6' gives the true equation $6-4=2$

Comment: Too small of an edit for me to suggest, but the numbers in the equation you wrote down are in the wrong order - not writing it here to prevent spoilers, but you need to swap 2 of the numbers around.

Comment: No problem, the maths was still correct, but it was killing my OCD!

Answer (score 7):

I suppose you could do:

> 5-4≠2 as well, because it's true!

Comment: That's an inequality, not an equation.

Comment: Whoops, I forgot about that

Comment: Alternately, almost the same, ≤

Comment: @Ruadhan2300 I'm not sure you can really make a ≤ moving only 1 line, I guess you could add an angled line above an `=`, but that would be pretty far from the normal representation of that symbol.

Comment: I've seen it written with two parallel lines and one angled in the past, though I'll admit it's not the norm. I think it'd be understood anyway :)

Comment: Can we just, as a general rule, say that messing with the = sign is forbidden on all matchstick equation puzzles?  It goes without fail that someone will suggest this every time.